# change the label size in an r plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinydashboard

I have used [SPCA](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/spca/)  package in r to find the loading factors. 
I created a plot to show the most important factors, but the names of kpis(labels) are not clearly visible. I used sizelabels in the plot function, It has changed the font size but still it is not clear. customer satisfaction in comp 2 is not readable.How Can I fix this problem?

```
 #reactuve function to analyse pca
  SPCA.results<-reactive({
    if(is.null(cor(EvaluatedData()))){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      #adapted from another devium
      file1<-input$evaluatedfile
      if(is.null(file1)){return()}
      dm<-data.matrix(cor(EvaluatedData())) 
      spca.components<-input$PCs
      spcabb(dm,card= c(spca.components, spca.components, 4),unc = TRUE) 
    }  
  })

    output$compplot<-renderPlot({
    if(is.null(SPCA.results())){return()}
    data<-SPCA.results()
    spca.components<-input$PCs
  plot(data, cols=3,plotload = TRUE,par(col = 'blue'), onlynonzero = FALSE, variablesnames = TRUE,plotvex = FALSE,mfrow = 2, mfcol = 2,addlabels = TRUE,sizelabels=1)

  })
```

[image: kpis]

Comment: You could start by providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated my codes and also I put the links for SPCA